# Convert ESRI Integer ASCII Grid to something useful

Tags: qgis, convert, esri-ascii-raster

How could I convert a file(s) which is *"DIGITAL Map data stored in ESRI ARCInfo Integer ASCII Grid format"* into something the rest of us can use? i.e import into QGIS.
The main file has no extension and is 70 MB, the accompanying files are a `*.dbf` and a `*.prj`.

It does appear to be of the format described here;
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid
but how do I convert it?

Comment: OK, by adding an *.asc suffix to the file I can get it to open in QGIS as a 1 band raster, with the default project projection. But I would like to associate the dbf information with it, presuming that there is more information here.

Comment: A .dbf file is not a standard part of an ASCII grid format.  Why don't you just open the .dbf file (with a spreadsheet, database, or GIS program) and see what's in it?

Comment: Hi W, the dbf seems to be some sort of key VALUE MAP_UNIT
1.00000 Undefined
2.00000 A1
3.00000 A10
4.00000 A11
5.00000 A12
6.00000 A13
7.00000 A14
8.00000 A15
9.00000 A16

Comment: Ah!  It must be an attribute table.  It is meant to be joined to the grid values.

Comment: Not much luck with QGIS, I had fair crack at it with GRASS but still need the attribute data to be tied in there somehow.   I'll work on your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

[gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)`-of gtiff foobar.asc foobar.tif`, where `.asc` is optional, will do the trick of converting to the more usable geotiff format (and save a whack of disk space too). I'm not sure how one would go about associating the attribute values to the raster cells in qgis, that could be a separate question as it's probably not file format specific operation.

Answer (score 1):

Arc ASCII grid files are single-band files. If you have not opened the *.dbf yet (for example, because Office 2007/2010 don't like dbfs), there is a free program DBF Commander that will open it for you and allow you to examine it and/or convert it to *.csv. The dbf... is it a vat.dbf? Value Attribute Table?

Answer (score 1):

I have found [R](http://www.r-project.org/) great for handling `dbf` files. I imagine it would work well to deal with both the raster and the `dbf` file in this instance. Using the package `foreign` you can read in a `dbf` as a dataframe manipulate it, and write out a `dbf` also. `foreign` is included in the default `R` installation.

For dealing with the raster I would use the package `raster` which has a lot of functionality for performing analysis. You read in anytime of raster (`.asc` is fine). For relating the `raster` and `dbf` together you might want to use the `merge()` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `.dbf` file to QGIS using `Add Vector layer`.

You get a geometryless layer with the attribute table which you can join to the raster or other vector files.