# Importing text file Arc/Info ASCII GRID into QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, import, esri-ascii-raster

I am trying to import gridded data from [BOM](http://www.bom.gov.au/jsp/ncc/climate_averages/degree-days/index.jsp) into QGIS.

The data is available as an Arc/Info ASCII GRID which is a text file with no accompanying files (unlike in this question [Convert ESRI Integer ASCII Grid to something useful](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14749/convert-esri-integer-ascii-grid-to-something-useful)).

I have tried using the Delimited Text option in the Data Source Manager but it is not point coordinates and as far as I can tell it is not WKT either.

I also tried resaving the text file as .asc and importing as a raster file but it says it is not a supported raster data source.

Comment: Does it have no header? See an example https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/esri-ascii-raster-format.htm I just downloaded the file and can see that it's an Esri ASCII, just change the extension to .asc and it should load just fine.

Comment: I usually try to drag and drop from the file explorer. I tried this file http://www.bom.gov.au/web01/ncc/www/climatology/degree-days/hdd12/hdd12an.zip (the text file inside) and it loads without issues, however it is not georeferenced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I noticed from the sample data that the prj file was missing. I just took the prj file from their sample data and it solved the issue.

Just take the content below and create a text file copy and paste the following:

> Projection    GEOGRAPHIC
> Datum         GDA94
> Zunits        NO
> Units         DD
> Spheroid      GRS1980
> Xshift        0.0000000000
> Yshift        0.0000000000
> Parameters

2. Save the text file as the same name as your grid file but .prj.
   ie.: hdd12ann.txt (the grid file), hdd12ann.prj for the projection.
3. Drag and drop the grid file in .txt format from the Window's File Explorer to QGIS canvas. Below is the result.

[image]

[image]